# ¿Cómo abrir una ventana jFrame cada vez que recorre un bucle?

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy haciendo un proyecto java de clase. La primera parte era hacer un juego tipo Saber y Ganar, donde seleccionabas los jugadores y las rondas. En cada ronda cada jugador tiene que contestar a una pregunta (puede ser de tres tipos, cálculo matemático, letras o inglés). Esto lo hice con doble bucle, el primero para las rondas y el de dentro para cada jugador. El problema viene en la segunda parte del proyecto, donde tenemos que transformar el juego de forma que tenga interfaz gráfica...cada vez que aparece una pregunta tengo que abrir una ventana jFrame con la pregunta y un jTextField para que el usuario introduzca la respuesta.
En la primera parte del proyecto, el bucle esperaba a que el usuario introduzca por teclado la respuesta antes de continuar...pero no sé como hacer esto con una nueva ventana jFrame. Dicho de otra manera, no sé qué hacer para que el bucle se espere a que el usuario introduzca la respuesta  y le dé al botón de continuar y que al hacer esto, se cierre la ventana y el bucle abra otra con la siguiente pregunta.
Muchas gracias, espero haberme explicado bien...

Comment: Si son diez preguntas ¿extenderías JFrame 10 veces? Considera usar [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input).

Answer (score 0):

me parece que el siguiente código podría servirte:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            new nuevoMarco();
        }
    }
}

class nuevoMarco extends JFrame{
    public nuevoMarco() {
        setBounds(500,300,500,300);
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel miPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField campo = new JTextField(20);
        miPanel.add(campo);
        add(miPanel);
    }
}
```

Lo que realiza el siguiente código es durante un bucle for que está programado para ejecutarse 100 veces. A cada vuelta del bucle instanciará la clase "nuevoMarco", que es como he llamado a los marcos que creará. Si deseas insertar más componentes swing (JTextField, CheckBox y más...), deberías hacerlo en un JPanel, que `para abreviar código he creado una intsancia de él en la clase que hereda de JFrame y a partir de ahí he agregado todos los componentes que necesito.
Espero que te haya podido ayudar.
Un Saludo.